# Add 0 in front of the value in excel by java

Tags: java, excel

Is there a way to add 0 in front of the value ?
In database record, I have a value with `00037`.When it written to excel, I get `37`, instead of `00037`.

```
  public static final String REF_NO = "REF_NO";
  custom.setRptDailyTxnRefNo(rs.getString(REF_NO));
  System.out.print(rs.getString(REF_NO))
```

Please let me know if you need more code.

The file is in `.xls`.

Comment: you have to format the cell as text and not as number. if you are using apache poi there is something called cellformat

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I write from java to netbeans,how do I customize it ?

Comment: i doubt you do that. as i know netbeans is an IDE and not an excel file

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I don't get you ><

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I just found an easier solution than changing the cellformat (which also works fine). You can simply write `'00037` in excel to have `00037` displayed. Just add the apostrophe at the beginning

Comment: I'm reading data from database and need to write to excel file

Comment: Please explain how I can do that in netbeans so the value I get in excel is 00037. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JohnJoe did you write to excel by hand? there are several libraries which help you with writing data into excel. a good one is apache poi. you first load your data from the database and then write it to excel. its hard to help you if we don't know the format of database and how it should look like in excel.

Comment: I can get all data, just the 0 that suppose to be show in front of the value did not shown

Comment: if you print in java or if you write into excel?

Comment: I print it in netbeans(console),data get displayed. I write them in  excel using java as well but the 0 not display in the excel.

Comment: you have to modify the as i suppose its a string value, so it is `String s="'00037";` instead of `String s="00037";` and write that into excel

Comment: So should be custom.setRptDailyTxnRefNo("`"+rs.getString(REF_NO)); ?

Comment: its not ` its an apostrophe. its above the hashtag (same key).

`custom.setRptDailyTxnRefNo("'"+rs.getString(REF_NO));`

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the answer given by @Xtreme, I found another one which does not require `'`

```
String abc = 0003;
formatToCVSValue(abc);

public static String formatToCVSValue(String s)
    {
        if(s==null || !hasLength(s))
            return "";
        else
        {
            return "\"=\"\""+s+"\"\"\"";
        }
    }
```

When open in excel, you will see exactly 0003 instead of `'0003`